Blazor Maui Auth Error: DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user
I recently set up an auth service within my Blazor MAUI .NET 8 application. The server side code seems to be working well however in my client it seems to not be configured correctly. Whenever I log in as one of the users, I get this error:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.

This is my login component:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject IAuthService AuthService
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthStateProvider
@using Components.Models.DTO
@using global::UCMaps.UCMaps

<AuthorizeView>
   <Authorized>
   </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <LoginForm OnLoginSuccess="HandleLoginSuccess" />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {
    private async Task HandleLoginSuccess()
    {
        await AuthService.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

This is where the error occurs.
In my loginform, it takes in basic user and password to which it calls the AuthService's Login function, which properly handles the user's JWT token. Whenever I call my NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged function and debug, I can see that it gives IsAuthenticated = true. The problem is though the rest of my application seems to still remain in an unauthorized stage. I believe that it could be due to a configuration error in my MauiProgram.cs, but it's hard to find much documentation for Bz Maui net 8 on the topic of authorization.
Here is my github for reference: https://github.com/JaredWalden00/UCMaps
Edit:
I ended up debugging and cross referencing different auth apps I've made, and noticed that when I hit this line:
_http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);

after logging in with correct credentials, the DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization becomes a bearer token. I then used that bearer token with my swagger API and it authorized me. BUT the MAUI Blazor side still gives me this error on the  sections. Could it be a global configuration issue?

About this error, you can see this case: ASP.NET Core 7 Web API - authorization failed. These requirements were not met: DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user. Try to add System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt nuget package.

My ASP.NET Core API is working fine and it's [Authorize] feature is also working. It's the  in my Blazor MAUI app that is causing this error.

In your application's razor pages add @attribute [Authorize]. If you navigate to a razor page without this attribute, the auth state is not being checked i.e. anyone can navigate to it even if they didn't successfully logged in

@Coop I did that on purpose. I want this page I referenced to be accessed by anyone so that they can login. The authorization gets checked through the AuthorizeView

"The problem is though the rest of my application seems to still remain in an unauthorized stage. "

I thought this was the problem?


@Coop Yes, there is certain features I want only access to authorized individuals, but doing something like a profile tab involves the  where I can set the visibility of a component based on  or . So I want the user to be able to access the page even if they are not authorized.

@Waldener I think the problem is having the AuthorzieView in anywhere else but Main.razor or whatever routing equivalent you have. Let that one single file handle routing and redirecting to login and all the rest of your components should be using Authorize attribute, except the login page (which is where the routing component will redirect to

On successful login, redirect from the login component to some other/page component that has Authorize attribute on it and if everything went well, you'll land there, otherwise the routing component will send you back to the login component (or give you "you're not authorized to  view this" or whatever logic you have implemented)
